# WatchKit large text input failure

Tags: watchkit, watchos

I am using `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions` in a `WatchKit` app. When I dictate a lot of text, the application hangs, there is only a cancel button. When I press cancel, all previously typed text is lost. The input language does not matter. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is your question about using dictation on the Watch or coding with `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions`?  I can't tell what part of that you're looking for help.